# QGIS 3.16 - Print layout grid coordinates in DMS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, print-composer

I am trying to create a grid with coordinates printed in degrees, minutes, and seconds in print layout of QGIS 3.16. The project is defined to EPSG:32652 WGS 84/UTM Zone 52N.

When I go to Grid > Draw Coordinates > Format, I do not get the usual DMS option. There are only three options: [image]

The following is what I get when I change to CRS to the default of EPSG:4326 - WGS 84, but when I choose the option, the coordinates still do not appear on the map:
[image]

What should I be doing to bring the DMS option using my project's CRS? Why am I only getting decimal, decimal with suffix, custom?

Comment: Are you able to show the grid?

Comment: Just want to say thank you for the answers, I had the same problem, and this solution fixed it perfectly (and the instructions are easy to follow)! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't display your project CRS coordinates in DSM as they are in metres. You need to change the CRS of the **grid** to EPSG:4326 to have a grid in degrees that will allow you to use DSM.

You will then need to adjust the spacing of the grid lines as when dealing with metres you probably had then set to 1000's of metres apart while with degrees you probably want 0.1 or 1 as the spacing.

Comment: Amazing! It was the spacing of the grid lines, I had missed it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: please accept the answer to help other people see that it is correct

Comment: Follow-up question: I'm using the "Decimal with Suffix" format to display my grid line X and Y intercepts, but I wish to see the grid coordinates drawn as '50 N', not '50.000 N'. Looks like I'd need to go "Custom" to get that degree of control, however I don't know what expression I'd use here..

Comment: There is a coordinate precision box at the bottom of the Coordinate properties that can be set to 0