# QGIS 3.18.1 Print layout grids are incorrect, cannot show them in DMS format

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Normally, in ArcMap Print layout, enabling the grids and specifying the intervals would show the **curved** grids as in the following map:

[image: Stock map of Mongolia]

But in QGIS, enabling the grids (1) does not have an option of showing the coordinates in DMS, (2) reveals wrong coordinates, (3) is not curved like in the previous map:

[image]

I assumed it was an error with the projections and made sure that the map was assigned the same CRS (WGS84 - UTM Zone 48N) as the project, but the last photo was still the result.

I saw a "[solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389070/qgis-3-16-print-layout-grid-coordinates-in-dms)" that changing the projection to EPSG:4326 WGS84 would supposedly allow for DMS units to be shown, but changing the projection to WGS84 returned an ugly output:

[image]

where the coordinates were still incorrect.

How would one go about (1) displaying the correct grid labels as DMS, (2) show the gridlines in a curved fashion on a map projected to UTM on QGIS 3.18.1?

Grid settings:

[image: Grid settings]

[image: Draw Coordinates settings]

Comment: Please provide your grid settings as screenshot.

Comment: Okay, I have added them in the post.

Comment: If you want DMS coordinates you need to set the CRS for the grid accordingly.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm fairly new to QGIS, and I haven't encountered settings for grid CRS other than that in the above photo. It's set to the CRS I want it to be projected to.

Comment: Set it to EPSG4326. That's the global CRS for DMS-values.

Comment: Yeah, but setting the grid projection to EPSG:4326 returns that weird output as in the post. If I set Project CRS to EPSG:4326, it doesn't show that distorted output as above, but the gridlines still show incorrect coordinates. Is there no equivalent way of showing grids like in the first map?

Comment: I am not talking about project CRS, but about grid CRS.

Comment: Yes, setting grid CRS to EPSG:4326 shows that distorted output... I want the map to look just like the first map I put in the post, with a UTM projection, curved gridlines and DMS annotations, but I haven't been able to achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **project** CRS should correspond to your main data, i.e. in UTM (`32648`)

If you want to show a grid in degrees, you must set the **grid** CRS to `4326`, and only then you can show the coordinates as decimal degrees or DMS.

[image]

Note: if your grid is in UTM and the coordinates are to be shown as degrees, the output is complete garbage.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I was wrongly fiddling with the project CRS inside QGIS > File > Properties, but learned that I was supposed to also specify the UTM projection in the Main Properties panel in the settings on the map element in the Print layout.