# Coordinates in the layout as DMS

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I'm new to QGIS and I'm having a problem displaying the coordinates in degrees, minutes and seconds as the option doesn't appear. Only appears as decimal and decimal with suffix in the format. How can I display DMS instead?

[image: Coordinate format]

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/389109/276